# React Axios not rendering after setState

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios, arrow-functions, setstate

I've got troubles with my Login component, I'm using the cointainer pattern, so i've got a component Login which manage the api call and a DumbLogin managing the input and warn the user about the response from my server.
I'm using Axios to do the api call, which use promises to do that, I'm also using  arrow function to avoid troubles wiht the this, well that's what i was thinking...
Because in the end I have

> TypeError: _this.setState is not a function

I tried to use a variable self to resolve that but that result in the same error.

How Am I suppose to do?

```
axios(all)
        .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 200){
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    spin: false,
                });
                let data = response.data;
                this.props.connect(data.username, data.email, data.token, data.partners);
                this.props.router.push('panel');
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response);
            this.setState({
                spin: false,
                errorLogin: 'Username or password wrong',
            });
        });
```

(spin is a boolean to inform DumbLogin that it should or not display a spinner while waiting for the response from my server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the  `this` inside of the anonymous function inside of the `then` is not the `this` of the React component.

you need to bind the correct `this`(Reac Component's this) for the function which does the ajax call.

eg. if the function is:

```
fetchData(){
    axios(all).then(...).catch(...)
}
```

you can bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor(){
   this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this)
}
```

HOWEVER!

This is not the recommended solution, you would usually dont want to do ajax call in the component... you may want redux, mobx or even redux-saga for this purpose